# Launch nunit tests from command line

Tags: c#, macos, command-line, nunit

I would like to be able to launch my nunit test from the command line but when I run

```
nunit-console myproject.csproj
```

I have this error :

> nunit-console shipped with Mono is deprecated, please use the NUnit
>   NuGet package or some other form of acquiring NUnit.

Any ideas?

Comment: NUnit version 2.4.8   OS Version: Unix 18.0.0.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000 ( 5.12.0.309 (2018-02/39d89a335c8 Thu Sep 27 06:54:53 EDT 2018) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NUnit error in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738742/nunit-error-in-xamarin)

Comment: See also https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99050/how-do-i-run-a-xamarin-ui-test-from-the-command-line-on-a-mac

Comment: No I dont have any probleme with the TestFixtureAttribute, I cannot launch nunit-console.

Comment: read the rest of the answer..... Updating NUnit might solve your problem